# Se pierden los estilos al agregar ComboBox mediante JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, combobox, bootstrap-3

Tengo un *ComboBox* con unos estilos de *Boostrap 3* y *JavaScript* que se muestran perfectamente, pero al agregar otra *ComboBox* con *JavaScript* también este pierden los estilos que posee el anterior:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group heading-group">
            <label class="control-label">Descripción del Producto</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group heading-group">
            <label class="control-label">Cantidad</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group heading-group">
            <label class="control-label">Costo</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="prods">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control chosen-select" id="product_id" name="product_id[]">
                    <?php foreach ($product as $row): ?>
                        <option value=<?=$row->product_id?> ><?=$row->product_code?> - <?=$row->product_name?></option> 
                    <?php  endforeach;?>
                </select> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="cant" name="cant[]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="product_cost" name="product_cost[]" readonly="true">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_prod" value="adicionar">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Nuevo Producto
            </button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Este es el código de la primera línea, mediante el botón adicional agrego varias líneas más utilizando este código:

```
var max_prod = 20;   //max 20 row
var x = 0;
$('#add_prod').click (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();   //prevenir nuevos clicks
  if (x < max_prod) {
    $('#prods').append(
'<div class="row" id="row">\
  <div class="col-sm-4">\
    <div class="form-group">\
      <select class="form-control chosen-select" id="product_id" name="product_id[]">\
        <?php foreach ($product as $row): ?>\
          <option value=<?=$row->product_id?> ><?=$row->product_code?> - <?=$row->product_name?></option> \
        <?php  endforeach;?>\
      </select>\
    </div>\
  </div>\
  <div class="col-sm-1">\
    <div class="form-group">\
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="cant" name="cant[]">\
    </div>\
  </div>\
  <div class="col-sm-1">\
    <div class="form-group">\
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="product_cost" name="product_cost[]" readonly="true">\
    </div>\
  </div>\
  <div class="col-sm-1">\
    <div class="form-group">\
      <a href="#" class="del_prod btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>\
    </div>\
  </div>\
</div>'
    );
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({
      width: '100%'
    });
    x++;
  }
});
// Remover el div anterior
$('#prods').on("click",".del_prod",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').remove();
  x--;
});
```

Pero por alguna razón los estilos que posee la primera línea o `row` no los tiene las otras.

He revisado varias cosas y no acabo de dar con el problema.

Comment: Podrás compartir un link en donde está realizado para inspeccionar o un [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Hola Delvis! Podrías armar un [mcve] que incluya el código y css relevante a este problema?

Comment: Bueno, asunto resuelto, el problema era en la llamada a una meta que llamaba a un funcion en js. En el select de productos habia que agregarle. ` <select class="form-control chosen-select" id="product_id" name="product_id[]"> ` En este caso chosen-select era la llamada que funcionaba al cargar la pagina pero cuando le agregaba uns filas nuevas con el uso de la funcion #add_prod no agregaba el estilo. Entonces lo que hice fue que en las misma funcion le agregue la llamada ` $('.chosen-select').chosen({
                        width: '100%'
                    });`

Comment: @DelvisDíaz Hola, si resolviste tu problema, porfavor responde la pregunta, de modo que pueda ayudar a otros que tengan u problema similar!

Comment: Edite el codigo de js que aparece arriba. Como esta en este momento funciona perfectamente. Garcias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si tu respuesta pudo solucionar el problema puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Al final queda así:

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({
    width: '100%'
});
```

Agrego esta llamada dentro de la misma función de *JavaScript* y me carga los estilos.